# Polymer's Ripple Animation Freezes due to <div> with Inset Shadow

Tags: html, optimization, web-applications, web, polymer

### Original Question

I have a web app that contains a `<polymer-element>` (`<inventory-list>`) which contains about 30 `<polymer-element>`s (`<inventory-card>`). Each `<inventory-card>` includes an image and some text. Whenever I tap a `<paper-button>` or `<paper-ripple>`, the ripple effect freezes at the beginning of animation, and then the ripple disappears.

When I remove `<inventory-list>`, the ripple animation animates properly.

*This only happens when I test on my mobile device (Nexus 7 running Android 5.0). I do not have this problem on desktop.*

---

**How do I stop the ripple animation from freezing?**

I am not interested in using `noink`.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Just to clarify, this is the structure of `<inventory-list>`

```
<polymer-element>
  <template>
    <div id="container">
      <template repeat="{{item in items}}">    <!-- {{items}} contains about 30 items -->
        <inventory-card>
```

And this the structure of `<inventory-card>`:

```
<polymer-element>
  <template>
    <paper-shadow>
      <paper-ripple/>
      <span/>
      <div id="inset-shadow"/>
      <img/>
```

---

### Update 1: The Shadow Causes The Freezing

When I removied `<div id="inset-shadow">` the ripple animation no longer froze.

The CSS I use to achieve the inset shadow is:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -30px 50px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

That div also has the following CSS attributes:

```
position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0;
```

**How could I achieve this type of inset shadow without causing the ripple animation to freeze?**